# How to commit to Subversion repository in a Jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins, svn, commit

Good afternoon,

I'm running a job in Jenkins, and I need to execute an `svn commit` to upload the results to my Subversion repository.

First, I have configured the source code origin to use the repository hosted in Subversion, using a valid user credentials and using an `svn update` as much as possible.

[image: jenkins-svn-repository_configure.png]

Then, I run my job and some files are modified.

Finally, I execute `svn add Packages/ --force` and `svn commit -m "Testing Jenkins Job"`.

[image: svn add and svn commit]

Up to `svn add` command the job runs correctly, but when executes `svn commit` I get the following error:

```
svn: E170013: Falló el commit (detalles a continuación):
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://svn...'
svn: E215004: No more credentials or we tried too many times.
Authentication failed
```

[image: jenkins job failure]

If I add the parameters `--username user --pasword pass` to the svn commit command, it works correctly, but I don't understand why it doesn't work without them, having configured the user credentials in the subversion configuration, and I don't want to leave the user's password written in the job script.

I tried to use an environment variable with the subversion credentials:

[image: credentials parameter]

But when I execute `echo ${SVN_CREDENTIAL}` it returns a string with the following format: `26c*****-****-****-****-*********671` and I need something like this: `--username user --password pass`

Does anyone know why the commit is not working or how I can use the password without typing it in plain text? Thanks in advance...

Comment: @Friedrich If I use the `svn login` command, it says that the command is unknown:

`svn login
Unknown subcommand: 'login'`

Comment: Probably my memories mislead me. Sorry for that. I'm glad you managed to figure it out.

Comment: @Friedrich No worries, thank you very much for your contribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem by making use of the Jenkins plugin "***Mask Passwords***". This plugin allows masking passwords that may appear in the console, including the ones defined as build parameters. Here is the link to the plugin: https://plugins.jenkins.io/mask-passwords/

After installing and enabling this plugin, it allowed me to check the following checkbox in the Jenkins job:

[image: Mask passwords]

So I was able to run the following command using a variable set as a password parameter: `svn commit -m "Jenkins Job - $date" --username user --password ${SVN_PASS}`

[image: svn pass parameter]

[image: backup in svn]

The console output of the command appears as follows:

[image: svn commit output]